# Getting variable from mySql to jQuery via ajax

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

I'm trying to get a variable to jQuery from mySql database.

Here's the php code, getTime.php:

```
include('connect.php');
$sql = "select * from timer";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $hours = $row['hours'];
    $minutes = $row['minutes'];
    //echo $hour.":".$minutes;
}
    $timeHour = $_POST['hours'];
    echo $timeHours;
```

Here's the ajax POST request for another file:

```
    var timeHour = "";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/getTime.php",
        data: timeHour
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert(timeHour);
    });
```

But the alertBox doesn't show anything.
It should be really easy, but i haven't found an example that it explains it.

**UPDATE**

Thanks! But now i have another problem - I want to use my variables "timerHours" and "timerMinutes"...

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "getTime.php",
                success: function(data){
                    //alert(data);
                    timerArr = data.split(":")
                    timerHours=timerArr[0];
                    timerMinutes=timerArr[1];
                }
            });
```

... but it gives 'undefined:undefined' - when i alert data - it works fine.

```
var today = new Date();
var endTime= new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate(), timerHours, timerMinutes , 00);
console.log(timerHours+":"+timerMinutes);//Console: undefined:undefined
var second = (endTime.getMinutes()-today.getMinutes())*60+(endTime.getSeconds()-today.getSeconds());
```

And if I put it on the doTime function and print it to the html it's working fine too.

```
function do_time() {
            //console.log(timerHours+":"+timerMinutes);//Console: 21:50
            second--;
            $("#timer").html("Time left: "+second);//Output: Time left: NaN
            $('#setTime').html("Hours: "+timerHours+" Minutes: "+timerMinutes);//Works fine too.
        }
```

Comment: What is outputted by your ALERT(DATA). You have commented it in the new question but we don't know if it does contain a ":". If not, it will never split correctly hence the reason for not working...

Comment: When does do_time gets executed? Is it executed AFTER your ajax is done? Because ajax is asynchronus, it means that you can't know when it will be filled...

Comment: First there is: just simple function in what you can find:
setInterval(do_time, 1000);

After that function comes the ajax.

Comment: I would start the interval in the ajax function so that it doesn't run for nothing and initialize your variables to 0 outside of the ajax. Thats all i could think about

Answer (score 1):

First of all your getTime.php probably returns nothing right now. Try calling it directly from your browser or check firebug what it is returning. Your code seems almost right but you are overriding it with a probably inexistent $_POST['hours']; Your code should look like this:

```
include('connect.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM timer";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $hours = $row['hours'];
    $minutes = $row['minutes'];
}
echo $hours.':'.$minutes;
```

Then, another problem is that you seem to be passing nothing to data in your ajax and expect it to return something into it. AJAX data is what you pass on to your server and what gets sent back is data that you have to work with, try this out instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/getTime.php",
        function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Good luck

Comment: Hi! Can you take a look at my new question in here?

Comment: Where is it? Give me the link so that people don't have to open your account and find your new question? Mostly if it's a followup it becomes pertinent, else you should never ask for someone to help you directly...

Comment: You have only one question on S-O, where is that question?

Comment: Sorry! I'm kind of new in stackoverflow - so i posted my related question as an answer in this quiestion. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8755216/1132458

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that you are trying to get the PHP time to POST to your page from an AJAX request.

```
include('connect.php');
$sql = "select * from timer";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $hours = $row['hours'];
    $minutes = $row['minutes'];
//echo $hour.":".$minutes;
}
// $timeHour = $_POST['hours']; This isn't needed.
echo $hour.":".$minutes;
```

And created ajax POST request for another file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "ajax/getTime.php",
       success: function(data){
           alert(data);
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi! Can you take a look at my new question in here?

Answer (score 1):

Set up your jquery like this.  The datastring variable will be passed through like $_POST variables.  So if you need to pass something, put it here.  If not, make it an empty string at least.

```
var dataString = 'hours=' + $("field#id").val();

$.ajax({  
    type: "POST", 
    url: "getTime.php",
    data: dataString,  
    success: function(data) {
        //create jquery object from the response html
        var $response=$(data);

        //query the jq object for the values
        var hours = $response.filter('div#hours').text();
        var minutes = $response.filter('div#minutes').text();

        $("label#hours").val(hours);
        $("label#minutes").html(minutes);
    }
});
```

Of course, this will only return the first result for hours and minutes.  If you need all of them, you would just put the above into a lool.  `$response.filter('div#hours').each()` or something.

Then, in `getTime.php`:

```
include('connect.php');
$sql = "select * from timer";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $hours = "<div id=\"hours\">".$row['hours']."</div>";
    $minutes = "<div id=\"minutes\">".$row['minutes']."</div>";
    echo $hours;
    echo $minutes;
}
```

Let me know if you have more questions.